# Having Trouble With Learning JOptionPane?

Tags: java, joptionpane, drjava

Instead of System.out.println for everything, I want to use JOptionPane. I don't know how to describe how my program is skipping code. If you could please take a look at this and help it go in order that would be highly appreciated.

```
//Step 1: Import Java APIs
 import java.util.InputMismatchException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.*;



//Step 2: Name File and Class
 public class GolfScores {




//Step 3: Declare All Variables  

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int hole9 = 0;
  int hole18 = 0;
  String holeChoice;

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


//Step 4: The program accepts INPUT from the user

  for (;;) {
   try {
 holeChoice =   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("For hole 9, please enter 9. If you are on hole 18, please enter 18 ");

     if (holeChoice.equals(9)) {
        System.out.println("The par for this hole is 3. Please enter if you this hole took you: "
                    + "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6+ shots");            
        hole9 = input.nextInt();

    } else if (holeChoice.equals(18)) {
        System.out.println("The par for this hole is 5. Please enter if you this hole took you: "
                    + "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8+ shots");
        hole18 = input.nextInt();

    } else if (holeChoice.equals(18)) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");
      continue;
    }
    break;
} catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
    System.err.printf("\nException: %s\n", inputMismatchException);
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
    input.next();
}
}


//Step 5 & 6: The user input is PROCESSED by Java and uses math to  calcualte an answer to output. The user's score is then output for them to see.
 if (hole18 == 1) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was a hole in one!");

 } else if (hole18 == 2) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was albetross.");

 } else if (hole18 == 3) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was eagle.");

 } else if (hole18 == 4) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was birdie.");

 } else if (hole18 == 5) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was par.");

 } else if (hole18 == 6) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was boogie.");

 } else if (hole18 == 7) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was double boogie.");

 } else if (hole18 >= 8) {
   System.out.println("You need some more practice at golf.");

 } else if (hole18 <= 0) {
   System.out.println("Please input a valid number.");
   input.next();

 }


   if (hole9 == 1) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was a hole in one!");

 } else if (hole9 == 2) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was birdie.");

 } else if (hole9 == 3) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was par.");

 } else if (hole9 == 4) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was boogie.");

 } else if (hole9 == 5) {
   System.out.println("Your score for this hole was double boogie.");

 }  else if (hole9 >= 6) {
   System.out.println("Your need some more practice at golf.");

  }

 try {
  Thread.sleep(3000);                
}     catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

    System.out.println("Thank you for playing Java Golf. Please come      again");

   }
```

}

Comment: What do you want it to do? any buttons?

Comment: Please describe what order it is actually executing in. I assume commented steps are what you're expecting

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Right now it skips all the way to "Please enter valid number" when either 9 or 18 is input into the JOptionPane. No buttons, just the simplest Pane will do. I just want to learn something more than System.out.println

Comment: Thanks to all who commented so quickly! Still errors in code being skipped so I just left the first and last message in a Pane which is enough for this purpose. Thanks again, -G4nd4lf-

Comment: You also have two conditionals that expect the same result, thus one of them will never be evaluated. It's the second of `else if (holeChoice.equals(18)) {`. You don't need the `continue` here either because there's no other code to skip. Also, the `break` is outside all of your `if` blocks, which means it will always break your loop regardless of user choice. The loop should only break if the user enters something valid.

Answer (score 2):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog` returns a `String`, you're comparing the result as if it was an `Integer`.

```
holeChoice =   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("For hole 9, please enter 9. If you are on hole 18, please enter 18 ");
//...
if (holeChoice.equals(9))  // this will always be false
```

If the user enters `9`, comparing it to the `int` `9` will not work, you need to add quotes to the values you check.

Ex:

```
if (holeChoice.equals("9"))
```

Likewise, you could also try to parse the input and turn it to an `int`, but you might open up the door for invalid user input (to which you'd need to check)

```
try {
   Integer choice = Integer.valueOf(holeChoice);
   //...
   if (choice.equals(9)) { // works now...
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
   // user didn't enter a number!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The returned value from `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` are String so use:

```
 if (holeChoice.equals("9")) { ... }
```

Or either parse the String to Integer using:

```
Integer.parseInt(holeChoice);
```